# which is the best way to create types in terms of performance in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

i have a RDBMS tables having multiple columns and its hetrogenous and need to create an index in elasticsearch from these tables. So which is the best practise intems of creation of types in elasticsearch. i was thinking about the multiple option
1) create types as same as rdbms tables and add documents as same as records in table
2) create a type with two fileds, in which one of the field for identification of that document and other field will be the concatenation of tables columns vales. So in this way only two fileds will be there across the all tables and search on the one field.

So could you let me know, which is the best way to create the types. please let me know, if need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Index the data in the form that best facilitates your search requirements.

If it makes sense to combine everything into one big searchable everything field, do that (by default, [elasticsearch already does this](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-all-field.html), in addition to the separate fields you index).  If you are going to regret not being able to separate them when you need to search for data from one particular column, go the other route.  If you need to know whether a document has been matched based on it's title or it's body, for instance, they should be indexed in different fields.

The best way to cripple your performance is trying to kludge together queries for things your index's structure doesn't support well.